# Classify tweets per topic

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, natural-language, feature-engineering

I am approaching machine learning for the first time because of my studies. I have been given a bunch of tweets and the goal is to classify them per topic. I really have no clue on how this should be done. Is there a particular way to follow?
Until now I have only found topics and I was thinking about making a DTM-like dataframe for the training containing not only the number of times not-sparse words accour but also the number of times particular N-grams accour and a ground truth column with the topic.
Is this totally wrong?
How else could I train a classifier without having features?

Comment: DTM: Document Term Matrix

Comment: Cross-posted: https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/25389/1794, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/133669/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/65456181/781723, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/502373/2921, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/87156/8560.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).